# When an eigenvector has a variable component, why it is said that this variable must be $0$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [this](https://youtu.be/k0zKoTvngUY?si=QQUkUits74t15mZi&t=12106) Linear Algebra course, in the eigenvectors part, the lecturer solves this determinant:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
   1-\lambda &0
\\ 0 &2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

And expresses each eigenvalue as follows:
$$
\lambda = 1: \begin{bmatrix}{} 0\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = 0\\
\lambda = 2: \begin{bmatrix}{} -x_1\\0\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

He then goes on to say ([link](https://youtu.be/k0zKoTvngUY?si=QQUkUits74t15mZi&t=12106)):

> In the case where our eigenvalue $\lambda$ equals $1$, we've got an eigenvector where the $x_2$ term must be 0, but we don't really know anything about the $x_1$ term. This is because any vector that points along the horizontal axis could be an eigenvector of this system. So we write that by saying: $@\lambda=1: x = \begin{bmatrix}{} t\\0\end{bmatrix}$

**question**: When eigenvalue $λ$ equals $1$, why it is said that the eigenvector's $x2$
term must be $0$? isn't it just the opposite? After all, it's the $x_1$ component in $\begin{bmatrix}{} 0\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$ which is $0$. I guess I'm missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving the homogeneous system $(A-I)x=0$ as follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
This represents the system:
\begin{align*}
0&=0\\
x_2&=0.
\end{align*}
So, $x_1$ is a free variable (can take any value) and $x_2=0$. The eigenvector is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks, the middle part of your answer clicked it for me.